# Update locked when using terminal command sudo apt-get update

Tags: command-line, updates

```
0% [Connecting to mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net (2a01:348:0:36::aaaa)]
```

I keep getting this message in the terminal when attempting to update in Ubuntu 16.04. I've never had this problem before in ten years! I've tried reinstalling but it didn't help.